How can I connect multiple 8V AC inputs into one earthed probe?
I am trying to design circuitry to connect 4 separate float-less water level controllers into one probe. Each unit needs to confirm that there is water in the tank and if not, will shut down. Not all units are necessarily running at the same time. Each unit uses a Omron 61F-GP-N float-less level controller (https://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/cat/61f-gp-n__ds_e_7_3_csm6.pdf) that connects to a probe in a tank of water. The output from each Omron level controller is 8 Volts AC and under 1 mA. If there in continuity through the water, then the units know that there is water in the tank. If I connect all units to the probe, they backfeed and don't recognize when the water level drops. Will it be as simple as putting a bridge rectifier in each connection before they link together at the probe? If so, what would be suitable bridge rectifiers? What design of bridge rectifiers and diodes would get me what I want?

Why do you need to do this and why do you think multiple controllers can be connected to a single sensor?

What is a "probe" from your point of view?

You can't. Use a single Omron controller, and use an additional 4-pole relay to notify the 4 devices about the water status coming out of the controller.

@Justme As I mentioned, I have 4 separate units that are not necessarily running at the same time. Each one needs to detect that there is water in the tank (by detecting continuity through the water), and if not safely shut down. If it was using DC it would work by using a diode on each connection.

@Marko Buršič The probe is an electrode into the tank of water as a specific level. This provides connectivity through the water to notify the Omron controller that there is water in the tank at that level.

@Dave Tweed That would work, but would require that I set up a separate device that is powered all the time with yet another Omron Controller. That can be done, but is not a simple solution. I was hoping for something to convert the AC to DC and then use Diodes to separate each of the 4 devices

I finally found an answer to my problem. It wasn't with any fancy connections, but using a different brand of level controller. The ABB CM-ENE MIN is able to interconnect with up to 4 other units without interfering with one another.
